# I clicked on “show pictures” in a malware e-mail

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, security, virus, malware

I carelessly pressed “show picture “in a spam e-mail that was in my unwanted folder

When i clicked the link just disappeared and no picture was shown.how worried should I be?

I did a disk clean-up after and ran my windows defender which found no threats

Comment: There is absolutely no way to know if the email did anything at all.

Comment: You may want to check to see if it added a task in your Task Scheduler.  I had some malware do that so it would re-infect my system in the future.

Comment: Disk clean-up and defender can't help. To be sure - reinstall OS but in 99% of case such malware used to steel passwords. So most probably it's already gone and you should immediately change password everywhere.